# JavaFX getText not working

Tags: javafx

My Controller looks like this:

```
public class MainController {

@FXML private TextField txtName;
@FXML private PasswordField txtPasswort;
@FXML private Button btnLogin;

@FXML
public void login() {
    System.out.println("login");
    System.out.println(btnLogin.getText());
}

}
```

And my FXML Buttons and Texts looks like this:

```
                        <Button id="btnLogin" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="18.0" layoutY="143.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#login" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="165.0" text="Anmelden" />
                    <PasswordField id="txtPasswort" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="87.0" promptText="Passwort" onAction="#login" />
                    <TextField id="txtName" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="50.0" promptText="Name"  onAction="#login"/>
```

When I click on the Login Button it prints out "login" but then crashes with a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` and a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. This happens for `System.out.println(txtName.getText());` and `System.out.println(txtPasswort.getText());` aswell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your FXML, change  the `id`s with `fx:id`

Comment: Thanks that did work!